# Why is the following $T:V \to V$ not surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear transformation and there exist $u_{1}, u_{2} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $u_{1} \neq u_{2}$ and for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the following holds: $T(u_{1}) \cdot v = T(u_{2}) \cdot v$, then why is $T$ not surjective?

I tried playing with the equations but so far I didn't find the way to prove this. Directions please?

Comment: I don't suppose we can assume that $V$ is finite dimensional?

Comment: You can. I edited my question. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll make two hopefully reasonable assumptions that you don't state in the question: $u_1\ne u_2$ and $V$ is finite dimensional.  Then $$T(u_1)\cdot v = T(u_2)\cdot v\quad \forall v \\ \implies [T(u_1)-T(u_2)]\cdot v = 0 \quad \forall v\\ \implies T(u_1-u_2)\cdot v = 0 \quad \forall v$$

The only vector $a$ such that $a\cdot v=0$ for all $v$ is the zero vector.  Thus $T(u_1-u_2)=0$.  From the assumption $u_1\ne u_2$, this implies $T$ has a nontrivial kernel.  Thus $T$ is not injective.  Endomorphisms on finite dimensional vector spaces are injective $\iff$ they are surjective.  Thus $T$ is also not surjective.

Comment: If $T$ has a nontrivial kernel then $T$ is not surjective? Doesn't it just mean that $T$ is not injective?

Comment: By rank-nullity, if $V$ is finite dimensional then a linear map $T: V \to V$ is injective if and only if it is surjective.